# Only persist data after submit in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using Ember.js and Ember-Data. Users can create and update resources, such as the `Organization` model. For the most part, the system works as expected. One exception is if a user partially fills out a form and then leaves the page without clicking submit. The partially created resource will persist on the client-side. (It's never submitted to the server and so never exists in the database. If the user reloads the page, these partially created resources disappear.)

My routes are fairly standard:

```
Whistlr.OrganizationsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @store.createRecord('organization')
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('content', model)

Whistlr.OrganizationEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @store.find('organization', params.organization_id)
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('content', @modelFor('organization'))
```

Perhaps the behavior I've described is also standard? If so, is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rollback` method from `DS.Model` to revert the local changes.

A good place to use it, is on [deactivate](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_deactivate) method of your route, where you have your form. So when the user exit of the route, the `deactivate` will be executed, and if have some dirty data, this will be cleaned.

Probally you will need to use the same logic in `OrganizationsNewRoute` and `OrganizationEditRoute`, so you can extract to a mixin:

```
Whistlr.CleanupRecordDataMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    deactivate: function() {
        this.get('controller.content').rollback();
    }
});

Whistlr.OrganizationsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend(Whistlr.CleanupRecordDataMixin, {
   // other methods
});

Whistlr.OrganizationEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend(Whistlr.CleanupRecordDataMixin, {
   // other methods
});
```

Comment: Beautiful. Deactivate and rollback seem like the right path, but the app freezes when I try to exit the form. Strangely, no error messages are thrown, even when I intentionally place buggy code with `deactivate`. If I place `alert("Pre")` before `this.currentModel.rollback();`, the alert pops up. If I place it afterwards, I get no alert--and no error message. This makes debugging a pain. At a glance, can you see anything wrong `this.currentModel.rollback();`. I'm using Ember-Data 1.0.0beta2, which might have changed the syntax somewhere. I'll update you if I find the answer.

Comment: Debugging in the Chrome console got me this error: `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'rollback'`.

Comment: Strange, what is returned from `this.currentModel.constructor`? Try to use `this.get('controller.content').rollback()` as a workaround, maybe work ...

Comment: `this.currentModel.constructor` returns `DS.RecordArray`. I'm not sure if that's what you expected or not. Thankfully, `this.get('controller.content').rollback()` get the desired behavior.